# Android App crashes when switching between activities

Tags: android, xml, crash, android-activity

My app was working absolutely fine when it suddenly started crashing after the first page. The first page only contains one button which leads it to the next activity. Helpppp

```
    package com.example.assignmenttwo;


    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button addReminder= (Button) findViewById(R.id.addReminder);
    addReminder.setOnClickListener(this); 
}


        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent ListofRemindersScr= new      Intent(this,ListOfReminders.class);
            startActivity(ListofRemindersScr);

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
```

}

Comment: put up the crash log from logcat

Comment: Can you please share your ListOfReminders code ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you registered your ListOfReminders in the Manifest ?

Like :

```
<activity android:name="your package name.ListOfReminders"></activity>
```

And why not just do like :

```
public class YourClass extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button addReminder = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addReminder);
        addReminder.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent ListofRemindersScr = new Intent(this,
                        ListOfReminders.class);
                startActivity(ListofRemindersScr);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

And don't forget your second activity to the manifest. Good Luck.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the debugger in either Eclipse or IntelliJ etc and find out where it falls over ... if asking people to determine the cause of the crash then it would help if you provided the backtrace and not expect them to compile and build your code. An Android app is more than just the java, there is the manifest, the layout etc too so people could not reproduce your issue even if they felt so inclined.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to include the ListOfReminders activity in the application manifest.

Comment: The manifest file is perfect. The app was running perfectly! I used SQLite in the next Activity. But how does that effect the previous activity. It just started crashing, I changed nothing in this file.

Answer (score 0):

You need register the activity in AndroidManifest file.

```
<activity
        android:name="PackageName.ActivityName"
        />
```

Answer (score -1):

From my experience i can definitely can tell You that sometimes it happens that there is no issue with the code but with the compiler. Try creating a new project and COPY PASTE the code from the old 1.

Good luck